# Integrating Clarifai Face Detection API into Final React App Zero to Mastery Bootcamp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, rest

*Please stop marking questions as solved because the question still has not been answered adequately.

I am taking the Complete Web Developer in 2022 course with Zero to Mastery and am working on a final project where we combine skills with both front and back end. We integrate an API from Clarifai that will detect faces from links we provide in our input and then within our code we have told it to create a box that will display on our chosen image displaying where the face is within the image.

I am having a very hard time making this happen. Clarifai seems to have updated a few things since the making of the tutorial - I don't know if this is causing any issue.

This is the repo on GitHub with all the code for a working project: https://github.com/aneagoie/smart-brain.

I have compared my code with the repo and haven't found any differences other than minor changes that shouldn't become breaking changes.

When I run this on my computer I use npm start and then run two instances in the terminal for the front end and back end files. This works great. When I put in a photo link, the photo comes up once I click detect but no box appears displaying where the face is in the photo.

I know there is a way to do this with Clarifai's gRPC but this project is meant to teach us how to use REST. I look in my console and don't see that I am logging any errors.

This leads me to believe that the Clarifai API is being accessed but for some reason my app is not registering where the face is being detected in the photo and not highlighting it

OR

when I am running two instances on the terminal, I am having to use a different port than is listed in my code for example have been using 3001 because the back end uses 3000 on localhost

OR

I am not accessing the Clarifai face detection API at all and am just not logging an error.

OR

Something is happening/not happening because I lack `registerServiceWorker()` which is included in the instructors code but we were told we did not need to include.

Please assist - I want to learn how we can adjust this as simply as possible to get it in working order. The solution will be helpful to other students taking the same course.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ParticlesOptions from './components/Particles/Particles';
import Clarifai from 'clarifai';
import FaceRecognition from './components/FaceRecognition/FaceRecognition';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
import Signin from './components/Signin/Signin';
import Register from './components/Register/Register';
import Logo from './components/Logo/Logo';
import ImageLinkForm from './components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm';
import Rank from './components/Rank/Rank';
import './App.css';

const app = new Clarifai.App({
  apiKey: 'MY API KEY GOES HERE'
});

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      imageUrl: '',
      box: {},
      route: 'signin',
      isSignedIn: false,
      user: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        entries: 0,
        joined: ''
      }
    }
  }

  loadUser = (data) => {
    this.setState({user: {
      id: data.id,
      name: data.name,
      email: data.email,
      entries: data.entries,
      joined: data.joined
    }})
  }

  // Connect to another piece of application
  // componentDidMount() {
  //   fetch('http://localhost:3000')
  //     .then(response => response.json())
  //     .then(console.log)
  // }

  calculateFaceLocation = (data) => {
    const clarifaiFace = data.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box;
    const image = document.getElementById('inputimage');
    const width = Number(image.width);
    const height = Number(image.height);
    return {
      leftCol: clarifaiFace.left_col * width,
      topRow: clarifaiFace.top_row * height,
      rightCol: width - (clarifaiFace.right_col * width),
      bottomRow: height - (clarifaiFace.bottom_row * height)
    }
  }

  displayFaceBox = (box) => {
    this.setState({box: box});
  }

  onInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({input: event.target.value});
  }

  onButtonSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input});
    app.models
      .predict(
        // HEADS UP! Sometimes the Clarifai Models can be down or not working as they are constantly getting updated.
        // A good way to check if the model you are using is up, is to check them on the clarifai website. For example,
        // for the Face Detect Mode: https://www.clarifai.com/models/face-detection
        // If that isn't working, then that means you will have to wait until their servers are back up. Another solution
        // is to use a different version of their model that works like the ones found here: https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-javascript/blob/master/src/index.js
        // so you would change from:
        // .predict(Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL, this.state.input)
        // to:
        // .predict('53e1df302c079b3db8a0a36033ed2d15', this.state.input)
        Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL,
        this.state.input)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('hi', response)
        if (response) {
          fetch('http://localhost:3000/image', {
            method: 'put',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
              id: this.state.user.id
            })
          })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(count => {
              this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, { entries: count }))
            })
        }
        this.displayFaceBox(this.calculateFaceLocation(response))
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  onRouteChange = (route) => {
    if (route === 'signout') {
      this.setState({isSignedIn: false})
    } else if (route === 'home') {
      this.setState({isSignedIn: true})
    }
    this.setState({route: route});
  }

  render() {
    const { isSignedIn, imageUrl, route, box } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ParticlesOptions />
        <Navigation isSignedIn={isSignedIn} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
        { route === 'home' 
          ? <div>
              <Logo />
              <Rank name={this.state.user.name} entries={this.state.user.entries} />
              <ImageLinkForm 
                onInputChange={this.onInputChange} 
                onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit}
                />
              <FaceRecognition box={box} imageUrl={imageUrl} />
            </div>
          : (
              route === 'signin' 
              ? <Signin loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
              : <Register loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
            )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript API is deprecated.

I was able to proceed with the course by calling the javascript REST API directly.
[Visit](https://docs.clarifai.com/api-guide/predict/images) for more information.

[This link](https://help.clarifai.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408131912727-How-do-I-find-my-user-id-app-id-and-PAT-)will also be of help in getting the required parameters

Answer (score 0):

use fetch() ,from clarifai ,
direct call as rest api

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem is not specific, I concluded that you don't know what's wrong with it, or having trouble implementing the new way of calling the APIs from the updated documentation of Clarifai. So, take a look at my codebase for this exact project. It's working...

Frontend: [Face-Detectionn](https://github.com/skywalkerSam/face-detection)

> App.js/jsx

```js
import { Component } from "react";
import './App.css';
import ParticlesBg from "particles-bg";
import 'tachyons';
import { Logo } from "./components/Logo/Logo";
import { Navigation } from "./components/Navigation/Navigation";
import { ImageBox } from "./components/ImageBox/ImageBox";
import { Entries } from "./components/Entries/Entries";
import { FaceDetection } from "./components/FaceDetection/FaceDetection";
import { SignIn } from "./components/SignIn/SignIn";
import { SignUp } from "./components/SignUp/SignUp";

const initialState = {
    input: '',
    imageUrl: '',
    box: {},
    route: 'sign-in',
    isSignedIn: false,
    user: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        entries: 0,
        joined: '',
    }
}

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = initialState;
    }

    loadUser = (data) => {
        this.setState({
            user: {
                id: data.id,
                name: data.name,
                email: data.email,
                entries: data.entries,
                joined: data.joined
            }
        })
    }

    onRouteChange = (route) => {
        (route === 'sign-out') ? this.setState(initialState)
            : this.setState({ route: route })
    }

    calculateFaceLocation = (data) => {
        // console.log('Clarifai Model Response:', data);
        const clarifaiFaceDetect = data.data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box;
        const image = document.getElementById('inputimage');
        const imageWidth = Number(image.width);
        const imageHeight = Number(image.height);
        // console.log(clarifaiFaceDetect, imageWidth, imageHeight)
        return {
            topRow: clarifaiFaceDetect.top_row * imageHeight,
            leftCol: clarifaiFaceDetect.left_col * imageWidth,
            rightCol: imageWidth - (clarifaiFaceDetect.right_col * imageWidth),
            bottomRow: imageHeight - (clarifaiFaceDetect.bottom_row * imageHeight)
        }
    }

    displayFaceBox = (box) => {
        this.setState({ box: box })
    }

    onInputChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ input: event.target.value })
        console.log('Image URL:', event.target.value);
    }

    onPictureSubmit = () => {
        this.setState({ imageUrl: this.state.input })

        fetch('https://face-detection-backend-one.onrender.com/imageurl', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                input: this.state.input
            })
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => this.displayFaceBox(this.calculateFaceLocation(result)))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))

        console.log('Fetching the Image... ')

        fetch('https://face-detection-backend-one.onrender.com/image', {
            method: 'put',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                id: this.state.user.id
            })
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(count => {
                // Object.assign doesn't creates a new object, it references to the original object!
                this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, { entries: count }))
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    render() {
        const { imageUrl, box, route, isSignedIn } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h1 className="red f3">Under Development!</h1>
                <ParticlesBg type="lines" num={3} bg={true} />
                <Navigation onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} isSignedIn={isSignedIn}></Navigation>
                <Logo onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}></Logo>
                {(route === 'face-detect') ?
                    <div>
                        <Entries name={this.state.user.name} entries={this.state.user.entries}></Entries>
                        <ImageBox
                            onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
                            onPictureSubmit={this.onPictureSubmit}>
                        </ImageBox>
                        <FaceDetection imageUrl={imageUrl} box={box}></FaceDetection>
                    </div>
                    : (route === 'sign-in') ?
                        <SignIn onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} loadUser={this.loadUser}></SignIn>
                        : (route === 'sign-up') ?
                            <SignUp onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} loadUser={this.loadUser}></SignUp>
                            : console.log('Routing Error Occoured...!')
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Backend: [Face-Detection-Backend](https://github.com/skywalkerSam/face-detection-backend)
( gRPC )

> server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const cors = require('cors');
const signup = require('./controllers/signup');
const signin = require('./controllers/signin');
const profile = require('./controllers/profile');
const image = require('./controllers/image');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3333;
const DATABASE_URL = process.env.DATABASE_URL;

const saltRounds = 10;

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const knex = require('knex')
const db = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        DATABASE_URL: DATABASE_URL,
    }
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => { res.json("Welcome to Face Detection API...") });

// Dependency Injection
app.post('/signin', (req, res) => { signin.handleSignin(req, res, db, bcrypt) });
app.post('/signup', (req, res) => { signup.handleSignup(req, res, db, bcrypt, saltRounds) });
app.get('/profile/:userId', (req, res) => { profile.handleGetProfile(req, res, db) });
app.put('/image', (req, res) => { image.handleImage(req, res, db) });
app.post('/imageurl', (req, res) => { image.clarifaiRequest(req, res) });


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    // console.log(`\nServer running on: http://localhost:${PORT} \n\nPress Ctrl+C to stop.`)
    console.log("Server is live and running...!")
})
```

> controllers/image.js (gRPC API Integration)

```js
const clarifaiRequest = (req, res) => {
    // Clarifai API: gRPC 
    const PAT = process.env.PAT;         
    const USER_ID = process.env.USER_ID;
    const APP_ID = 'face-detection';
    const MODEL_ID = 'face-detection';
    const MODEL_VERSION_ID = '6dc7e46bc9124c5c8824be4822abe105';
    const IMAGE_URL = req.body.input;

    const { ClarifaiStub, grpc } = require("clarifai-nodejs-grpc");

    const stub = ClarifaiStub.grpc();

    // This will be used by every Clarifai endpoint call
    const metadata = new grpc.Metadata();
    metadata.set("authorization", "Key " + PAT);

    stub.PostModelOutputs(
        {
            user_app_id: {
                "user_id": USER_ID,
                "app_id": APP_ID
            },
            model_id: MODEL_ID,
            version_id: MODEL_VERSION_ID, // This is optional. Defaults to the latest model version
            inputs: [
                { data: { image: { url: IMAGE_URL, allow_duplicate_url: true } } }
            ]
        },
        metadata,
        (err, response) => {
            if (err) {
                throw new Error(err);
            }

            if (response.status.code !== 10000) {
                // console.log(IMAGE_URL)
                throw new Error("Post model outputs failed, status: " + response.status.description);
            }

            // Since we have one input, one output will exist here
            const output = response.outputs[0];

            // console.log("Predicted concepts:");
            // for (const concept of output.data.concepts) {
            //     console.log(concept.name + " " + concept.value);
            // }
            // console.log(output)
            return res.json(output)
        }

    );
}

const handleImage = (req, res, db) => {
    const { id } = req.body;
    if (!id) {
        return res.status(400).json("Invalid Form Submission...!");
    }
    db('users').where({ id })
        .returning('entries')
        .increment('entries', 1)
        .then(entries => {
            (entries.length) ? res.json(entries[0].entries)
                : res.status(400).json("Entry not found...!");
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error updating entries..."));
}

module.exports = {
    handleImage,
    clarifaiRequest
}
```

Edit the `Environment variables` as needed, i hope it helps...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35650516)